# jms queuebrowser # getEnumeration always obtained as empty

Tags: java, spring, jms, messaging

I'm using jbossall-client jar for JMS and I'm new to messaging. Whenever I try to browse the queue to which I send a message (its an object message), always I'm getting 'false' on my `qBrowser.getEnumeration().hasMoreElements();`

This is how I create the connection:

```
 public void initialize() throws Exception {
  try {
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(contextProperties);
    connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(connectionFactoryName);
    queue             = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/" + queueName);
    initialContext.close();
  } catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new Exception("Error initializing enqueuer for " + queueName, e);
  }
}

 public MyQueueConnection openQueueConnection() throws JMSException {
  QueueConnection connection = null;
  try {
    connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    connection.start();

    QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(true, QueueSession.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    QueueSender  sender  = session.createSender(queue);
    sender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

    return new MyQueueConnection(connection, session, sender);

  } catch (JMSException e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Do I need to configure anything with QueueConnection/QueueSession/QueueSender or something else to browse the messages in a queue? Is it something I need to configure in jboss properties? (I do this in a singleton-MDB; this project is a spring framework project)

Please advise; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for another one.
I used hornetQ

1. Please check you created QueueReceiver createReceiver() **after** getEnumeration() is called.
2. Make sure you start connection **connection.start()**

[Check the link for bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1190) 
[Check the custom size](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/flow-control.html)